# My <select> options wont show in my email form submissions

Tags: php, html, forms, select, html-email

```html
<form id="ContactForm" method="post" action="php/test2.php">
  <div class="wrapper"> <strong>What cabin category are you interested in?</strong><br>
    <select name="cat1" size="1" tabindex="31">
      <option selected>Seclect Cabin Category</option>
      <option value="Bunk Beds">Bunk Beds</option>
      <option value="Minimum Inside">Minimum Inside </option>
      <option value="Mid Inside">Mid Inside </option>
      <option value="Highest Inside">Highest Inside </option>
      <option value="Atrium View">Atrium View</option>
      <option value="Boardwalk View">Boardwalk View</option>
      <option value="Neighborhood View">Neighborhood View</option>
      <option value="Promenade View">Promenade View</option>
      <option value="Obstructed Oceanview">Obstructed Oceanview</option>
      <option value="Minimum Oceanview ">Minimum Oceanview </option>
      <option value="Mid Oceanview ">Mid Oceanview </option>
      <option value="Highest Oceanview">Highest Oceanview </option>
      <option value="Balcony - Neighborhood">Balcony - Neighborhood</option>
      <option value="Balcony - Promenade">Balcony - Promenade</option>
      <option value="Balcony - Oceanview">Balcony - Oceanview</option>
      <option value="Balcony - Park View">Balcony - Park View</option>
      <option value="Mini Suite - Balcony">Mini Suite - Balcony </option>
      <option value="Suite - Balcony ">Suite - Balcony </option>
      <option value="Family Suite - Balcony">Family Suite - Balcony</option>
      <option value="Penthouse - Balcony">Penthouse - Balcony</option>
    </select>
    <strong>Second:</strong>&nbsp;
    <select name="cat2" size="1" tabindex="32">
      <option selected>Seclect Cabin Category</option>
      <option value="Bunk Beds">Bunk Beds</option>
      <option value="Minimum Inside">Minimum Inside </option>
      <option value="Mid Inside">Mid Inside </option>
      <option value="Highest Inside">Highest Inside </option>
      <option value="Atrium View">Atrium View</option>
      <option value="Boardwalk View">Boardwalk View</option>
      <option value="Neighborhood View">Neighborhood View</option>
      <option value="Promenade View">Promenade View</option>
      <option value="Obstructed Oceanview">Obstructed Oceanview</option>
      <option value="Minimum Oceanview ">Minimum Oceanview </option>
      <option value="Mid Oceanview ">Mid Oceanview </option>
      <option value="Highest Oceanview">Highest Oceanview </option>
      <option value="Balcony - Neighborhood">Balcony - Neighborhood</option>
      <option value="Balcony - Promenade">Balcony - Promenade</option>
      <option value="Balcony - Oceanview">Balcony - Oceanview</option>
      <option value="Balcony - Park View">Balcony - Park View</option>
      <option value="Mini Suite - Balcony">Mini Suite - Balcony </option>
      <option value="Suite - Balcony ">Suite - Balcony </option>
      <option value="Family Suite - Balcony">Family Suite - Balcony</option>
      <option value="Penthouse - Balcony">Penthouse - Balcony</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

There is a copy of the HTML 
And here is the way that the answers are being pulled from the form through a  PHP script

```
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Secondary cruise date:</strong></td><td>" . strip_tags($POST['sdm2']) . "/" . strip_tags($_POST['sdd2']) . "/" . strip_tags($_POST['sdy2']) . "</td></tr>";

$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Ship/Itenerary:</strong></td><td>Ship:" . strip_tags($POST['ship']) . "&nbsp;Itenerary:". strip_tags($_POST['iten']) . "</td></tr>";
```

On the tip of the PHP script there is the Data Library thats makiing the values for whats being pulled (if that makes sense, its my own way of looking at it)

```
//Data Library
$prefix = $_POST['p_prefix'];
    $firstname = $_POST['p_firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['p_lastname'];
    $address = isset($_POST['p_address']) ? $_POST['p_address'] : '';
    $city = $_POST['p_city'];
    $state = $_POST['p_state'];
    $zip = $_POST['p_zip'];
    $phone = $_POST['p_number'];
    $email = $_POST['p_email'];
    $passengers = $_POST['ad1'];
    $children = $_POST['cd1'];
    $cabins = $_POST['cab1'];
    $cruiseline1 = $_POST['line1'];
    $nights1 = $_POST['n1'];
    $destinations1 = $_POST['dest1'];
    $cruiseline2 = $_POST['line2'];
    $nights2 = $_POST['n2'];
    $destinations2 = $_POST['dest2'];
    $seconddate = $_POST['sdm2'];
    $seconddate2 = $_POST['sdd2'];
    $seconddate3 = $_POST['sdy2'];
    $ship = $_POST['ship'];
    $iten = $_POST['iten'];
    $air = $_POST['air'];
    $aircity = $_POST['aircity'];
    $category1 = $_POST['cat1'];
    $category2 = $_POST['cat2'];
    $spec = $_POST['special'];
    $occasion = $_POST['occasion'];
    $weddingmonth = $_POST['wd1'];
    $weddingday = $_POST['wd2'];
    $weddingyear = $_POST['wd3'];
    $submit = $_POST['f_submit'];
    $antispam = $_POST['aspam'];
```

used to create the form and process it to an HTML email. The result comes out like this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsjrE.png)
It shows the input text but not the `<select>` elements answers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry first time using it

Comment: Questions like this are the reason why SO doesn't allow posting jsfiddles without code! And why did you put PHP inside the JS area?!

Comment: Wasnt sure where else i could of put it

Comment: Here, in the question, and with proper description of the code and the issue you're having

Comment: Says it was to much code

Comment: That's why you need to edit it making a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The form itself is 40k characters

Comment: Im sorry i did it that way but its the best way i personally could think of

Comment: @miessau, Sorry you're having a rough first question.  Normally these things go much quicker.  A proper question should have example code of what you have, where you are and what you're trying to achieve.  For your specific question, you're going to need to post your `<select>` box, the way your form is being posted and where you pull the value after the post.  Remove everything else that doesn't pertain to that

Comment: @ntgCleaner, Thank you for the response, I have updated it and i Hope that is better then what i had in the beginning otherwise people will keep down voting and i don't know what happens then.

Comment: @miessau Sorry for my outburst. Please see my answer, now when your question is much more clear

Comment: Have done the Necessary Changes, however its still not showing anything on the area that the select answers go, I also updated the html code

Comment: The Changes are all made and the HTML is set to how it is supposed to be but yet still there is some of the answers missing when the form comes in

Comment: So i just updated the original code showing where the form is going and the form itself. well a part of the form that isnt working

Answer (score 1):

Oh, for heaven's sake - It was very hard to understand your issue.

Please take a look at one of the `<select>`s from your example:

```
<select name="p_prefix" size="1" tabindex="1">
            <option>Mr.</option>
            <option>Mrs.</option>
            <option>Ms.</option>
            <option>Dr</option>
</select>
```

None of the `<option>` has a `value` attribute, that's why nothing showing on the server (What you put inside the `value` is what is actually being sent to the server). You need to change this:

```
<select name="p_prefix" size="1" tabindex="1">
            <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
            <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
            <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
            <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
</select>
```

And of course you should add this attributes to all the other elements as well.

Comment: Thank you i will test this now, I have updated the question for a better idea hopefully.

Comment: Added values to everything and still Not showing the answers from the <select> answers

Comment: Please try and read this tutorial http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-select.html This is how you're setting a value (as I explained) Are you sure you don't have other field with the same `name` and that you're outputting the corrrect field from `$_POST`?

Comment: That article is showing how to basically add PHP to a form to validate the answers right? The script i have does  that aspect. It's just that when i get the form that was submitted by the end user everything shows up in the html email, except the answers from the <select> elements.

Answer (score 0):

As much i understand it Seems like `<form>` element is missing with form attribute method="POST" and action="someFile.php".

Your simplified code must be like this:

Html file:

```
<form action="formProcess.php" method="POST">
<div class="wrapper"> <strong>Second cruise departure date:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <select name="sdm2" size="1" tabindex="26">
                    <option selected>Month</option>
                    <option value="Januart">January</option>
                    <option value="Feburary">February</option>

                  </select>
                  &nbsp;
                  <select name="sdd2" size="1" tabindex="27">
                    <option selected>Day</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>

                  </select>
                  &nbsp;
                  <select name="sdy2" size="1" tabindex="28">
                    <option selected value=" ">Year</option>
                    <option value="2016">2016</option>
                    <option value="2017">2017</option>

                  </select>
                  <div class="wrapper"> <strong>Do you need airfare:</strong>&nbsp;
                    <select name="air" size="1" tabindex="29">
                      <option value ="No" selected>No, I Do Not Need Airfare</option>
                      <option value="Yes">Yes, I Do Need Airfare</option>
                    </select>

                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
```

formProcess.php should look like this:

```
<?php

$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Secondary cruise date:</strong></td><td>" . strip_tags($POST['sdm2']) . "/" . strip_tags($_POST['sdd2']) . "/" . strip_tags($_POST['sdy2']) . "</td></tr>";

$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Ship/Itenerary:</strong></td><td>Ship:" . strip_tags($POST['ship']) . "&nbsp;Itenerary:". strip_tags($_POST['iten']) . "</td></tr>";

echo $message;

?>
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: have all of that in my files just how you have it written there.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong.

In my PHP script the lines that were not returning an answer was 
" . strip_tags($POST['value']) . "

I just went through the code and replaced it with the proper "$_POST" and it was solved.

Such a small mistake
I appreciate the help from everyone thank you for all the advice it just takes me on a journey to becoming a better developer.